# Kendo Calendar Navigation With Events

Tags: events, cordova, calendar, navigation, kendo-ui

I'm trying to embed a calendar into my mobile application which is build using KendoUI mobile and I wanted to use Kendo's Calendar as it gives me more control and styling options than other jQuery calendars...So far I am able to select a day and save an event for that day which changes color pointing that its full. So far its working great but the only problem I am facing is when I navigate to another month/view and return back, all these events are removed as if the calendar is reinitialized.
I really need to be able to store those events "permanently" until they are being synced with the device's calendar app.

Answer (score 1):

Using a kendo datasource, after you do any adding/updating/deleting you need to call .sync() on your datasource. This will persist the updated datasource values into either your local variable you have data set to or it will call whatever transport methods are defined if using services.